# What is the range for Arabic-Indic Digits (Hindu–Arabic) numeral utf8 from 0 to 9

Tags: regex, utf-8, arabic, numerical

What is the range for Arabic-Indic Digits (Hindu–Arabic) numeral utf8 from 0 to 9 for the use in regular expressions:

[image]

to use in regex.

Comment: http://www.utf8-chartable.de/

Comment: @WaleedAkleh, If you actually used that chart, you'd find the answer that Joey gave below:  U+06F0-9.  Rather than being called Hindu-Arabic Numerals, they're listed as Extendend Arabic-Indic Digits.

Comment: Every character that hasn’t a special meaning in regex, can be used to stand for itself. So, `[٠-٩]` will match the arabic-indic digits from `٠` to `٩` and `[۰-۹]` will match the extended  arabic-indic digits from `۰` to `۹`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

U+06F0–U+06F9. As can be easily seen when checking a Unicode code point chart or the Character Map.

Answer (score 0):

finally I found the answer

for only numbers: \x{0660}-\x{0669}

for numbers and letters: \x{0600}-\x{06ff}

[Unicode 4.0 / ISO 10646 Plane 0](ftp://www.columbia.edu/kermit/public_html/utf8-t1.html)

thanks you all.