# pattern matching in malayalam makes TypeError: expected string or buffer

Tags: python

this program shows TypeError: expected string or buffer

```
# coding=utf-8
import re

s = [u'ഓ൪മകളൂടെ  സുഗന്ധം  പേറുന്ന  ഒരു  പൂക്കാലം.'] 

v={'q':s[0].encode('utf-8')}

match = re.search(r'സുഗന്ധം', s)
if match:                      
    print 'found', match.group() 

else:
    print 'did not find'
```

Comment: I don't think one can use re for other transcripts / alphabets

Comment: see, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14859957/regular-expressions-with-indian-characters

Comment: how should i do pattern matching in malayalam can i get the code

Comment: Googd luck, I really can't help more on this but you could install nltk to tokenize your words then apply regex to your tokens: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19515595/how-to-tokenize-a-malayalam-word

Comment: yes i have installed nltk

Comment: which version of python are you using? Python 2.7.x or Python 3.3.x?

Comment: @Ashwin: most likely it's Python 2 because of the print statement

Comment: @bernie gotcha :) the print statement was lost in the text before the edit

Comment: Python version (currently v2.7).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using [`re.search`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search), which expects a pattern and a string. 
You gave the second parameter as a list.
And you have indicate that your regex search string is unicode. So use `u'സുഗന്ധം'`
Testing on a string, it works -

```
import re
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
s = u'ഓ൪മകളൂടെ സുഗന്ധം പേറുന്ന ഒരു പൂക്കാലം.'
pat = re.compile(u'സുഗന്ധം')
match = re.search(pat, s)
if match:
    print match.group()
#OUTPUT - സുഗന്ധം
```

Comment: Is there any way to print the output(malayalam) clearly in the terminal.

Answer (score 2):

(Aside: I approved an to edit the question but it needs another approver.)

You have a couple of issues with this line:

```
match = re.search(r'സുഗന്ധം', s)
```

Issues:
1. The first argument should NOT be a raw string.
2. `s` is a list. This is where the `TypeError` occurs as `re.search` expects a string for the second argument.

Instead do:

```
match = re.search(u'സുഗന്ധം', s[0])
```