# Search for repeated arabic (hindi) numerals in a string

Tags: php, regex, unicode, arabic

I am trying to determine whether a given strings contains more than 4 consecutive arabic (hindi) numerals. to be specific, arabic (hindi) numerals are :

```
١ ٢ ٣ ٤  ٥ ٦ ٧ ٨ ٩
```

which are unicode 661 to 669

I tried :

```
if (preg_match("/\b(?:(?:١|٢|٣|٤|٥|٦|٧|٨|٩)\b\s*?){4}/", $str, $matches) > 0) 
        return true;
```

But it doesn't work at all (always returns false).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try the following regular expression. `\p{N}` matches any kind of numeric character in any script.

```
preg_match('~(?:\p{N}\s?){4,}~u', $str, $matches)
```

If you just want to match those [specific characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14834846/what-is-the-range-for-hindu-arabic-arabic-indic-numeral-utf8-from-0-to-9), you could use the following instead.

```
preg_match('~(?:[\x{0660}-\x{0669}]\s?){4,}~u, $str, $matches)
```

Comment: Is it possible to have it match everything except zero (in all languages also) ?

Comment: You could use negative lookahead, adding zero in every language to a character class. `(?![0०೦൦௦౦٠])\p{N}`

Comment: I mean I want it to skip matching of 0 - only match 1..9. I will try with the negative lookahead.

Answer (score 2):

Use a character class and quantify it. See this regex:

```
/[١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩]{4,}/
```

Your characters are not word characters, so `\b` would assert a word character in front of / behind your match, remove it.

Here is a [regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/oY5nA8/2).

As a note, if you are matching *more than* 4 characters, use `{5,}` instead.

Comment: This works fine in the regex demo, but using it in preg_match does not work properly. "Omar١٢٣" returns a positive match.