# How to parse string datetime & timezone with Arabic-Hindu digits in Java 8?

Tags: java, datetime, java-8, locale, arabic

I wanted to parse string datetime & timezone with Arabic-Hindu digits, so I wrote a code like this:

```
    String dateTime = "٢٠٢١-١١-٠٨T٠٢:٢١:٠٨+٠٢:٠٠";
    char zeroDigit = '٠';
    Locale locale = Locale.forLanguageTag("ar");
    DateTimeFormatter pattern = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX")
            .withLocale(locale)
            .withDecimalStyle(DecimalStyle.of(locale).withZeroDigit(zeroDigit));
    ZonedDateTime parsedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(dateTime, pattern);
    assert parsedDateTime != null;
```

But I received the exception:

> java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '٢٠٢١-١١-٠٨T٠٢:٢١:٠٨+٠٢:٠٠' could not be parsed at index 19

I checked a lot of questions on Stackoverflow, but I still don't understand what I did wrong.

It works fine with `dateTime = "٢٠٢١-١١-٠٨T٠٢:٢١:٠٨+02:00"` when the timezone doesn't use Arabic-Hindu digits.

Comment: @OleV.V. I mean this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Arabic_numerals

Comment: Like @OleV.V. mentioned, ISO formats need ASCII numerals. Hence, before you subject the to a `DateTimeFormatter`, convert the digits using the mapping shown in this SO question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14834846/what-is-the-range-for-arabic-indic-digits-hindu-arabic-numeral-utf8-from-0-to.

Comment: @SreeKumar Thanks. Interesting to see that your link indeed uses the term *Hindu–Arabic* about those digits. I don’t think I’ve seen or heard that before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `dateTime` string is wrong, misunderstood. It obviously tries to conform to the ISO 8601 format and fails. Because the ISO 8601 format uses US-ASCII digits.

The classes of java.time (`Instant`, `OffsetDateTime` and `ZonedDateTime`)  would parse your string without any formatter if only the digits were correct for ISO 8601. In the vast majority of cases I would take your avenue: try to parse the string as it is. Not in this case. To me it makes more sense to correct the string before parsing.

```
    String dateTime = "٢٠٢١-١١-٠٨T٠٢:٢١:٠٨+٠٢:٠٠";
    char[] dateTimeChars = dateTime.toCharArray();
    for (int index = 0; index < dateTimeChars.length; index++) {
        if (Character.isDigit(dateTimeChars[index])) {
            int digitValue = Character.getNumericValue(dateTimeChars[index]);
            dateTimeChars[index] = Character.forDigit(digitValue, 10);
        }
    }
    
    OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse(CharBuffer.wrap(dateTimeChars));
    
    System.out.println(odt);
```

Output:

> 2021-11-08T02:21:08+02:00

Edit: It will be even better, of course, if you can educate the publisher of the string to use US-ASCII digits.

Edit: I know the Wikipedia article I link to below says:

> Representations must be written in a combination of Arabic numerals
> and the specific computer characters (such as "-", ":", "T", "W", "Z")
> that are assigned specific meanings within the standard; …

This is one thinkable cause of the confusion. The article *Arabic numerals* linked to says:

> Arabic numerals are the ten digits: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 and 9.

Edit: How I convert each digit: `Character.getNumericValue()` converts from a `char` representing a digit to an `int` equal to the number that the digit represents, so `'٠'` to 0, `'٢'` to 2, etc. It works for all characters that are digits (not only Arabic and ASCII ones). `Character.forDigit()` performs sort of the opposite conversion, only always to US ASCII, so 0 to `'0'`, 2 to `'2'`, etc.

Edit: Thanks to @Holger for drawing my attention to `CharBuffer` in this context. A `CharBuffer` implements `CharSequence`, the type that the `parse` methods of java.time require, so saves us from converting the `char` array back to a `String`.

### Links

- [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)
- [Wikipedia article: Arabic numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_numerals)

Comment: In the loop where you are using the code point, if you use the ASCII to Arabic numeral mapping in this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14834846/what-is-the-range-for-arabic-indic-digits-hindu-arabic-numeral-utf8-from-0-to - it will be more accurate, I think. Or have I got your code wrong?

Comment: @SreeKumar we can not tell whether you got the code wrong, as you didn’t explain why you think, this code didn’t handle the digits correctly or why a Q&A not even containing code “will be more accurate” (more accurate in what regard?).

Comment: @SreeKumar I am passing a `char` to both `Character.isDigit(char)` and `getNumericValue(char)`. For Arabic digits I doubt that it makes any difference.

Comment: Where in the question is an ISO 8601 format used?  I can see that the format is essentially identical to ISO 8601, but it’s a new, localized DateTimeFormatter, not one of the ISO 8601 static fields of DateTimeFormatter.  I think the question is really about whether the offset field uses localized digits.

Comment: @VGR It’s my interpretation. To me it’s clear. Feel free to disagree about it. I’d welcome your answer too and be interested.

Comment: @Holger @OleV.V. My mistake. I mistook `Character.getNumericValue()` to be returning code points for numerals other than the ASCII set. However, it seems to be converting the Arabic numerals to ASCII correctly.

Comment: @SreeKumar Thanks for spelling your mistake out. I think others could make the same, so I have added a paragraph explaining.

Answer (score 4):

The error message states that the problem is at index 19 in the input string.

Character 19 is the `+` character in your input string.  This means the offset (represented by `XXX` in your pattern) cannot be parsed.

The problem is not the `+` itself.  The problem is that timezone offsets, like `+05:00`, are never localized.

The documentation doesn’t talk about this, so I had to go to the source code of DateTimeFormatterBuilder to verify it.

Inside that class is [this inner class](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.java#L3815):

```
static final class OffsetIdPrinterParser implements DateTimePrinterParser {
```

In that class, we can find a [parse method](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.java#L3902) which has calls to the private [parseHour](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.java#L4015), [parseMinute](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.java#L4027), and [parseSeconds](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.java#L4035) methods.

Each of those methods delegates to a private [parseDigits](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.java#L4049) method.  In that method, we can see that [only ASCII digits are considered](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.java#L4063):

```
char ch1 = parseText.charAt(pos++);
char ch2 = parseText.charAt(pos++);
if (ch1 < '0' || ch1 > '9' || ch2 < '0' || ch2 > '9') {
    return false;
}
```

So, the answer here is that the timezone offset must consist of ASCII digits, regardless of the locale.

Comment: Nice and curious (+1)

Comment: Nice observation about the digits in the timezone. I think @OleV.V.'s code to translate the text into ASCII numerals will take care of it now.